# Jquery touch devices

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, touch

I have a problem.
I made this effect at this link http://www.doppiacopia.com/indexDesktop.html
and i must be recreate this effect on touch devices.

There is a solution, create a virtual mouse?

Or an another solution?

Thanks,

Daniele

Comment: You can use [`jQuery Mobile`](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html).

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no mouse there is nomouseover event in touch devices. You can only tap or swipe 
in there . However you can use jQuery mobile and use its vmouseover event to handle mouseover virtually.Although it is normalized for normal mouseevents. you can give it a try.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: I am not very expert in jquery,

Comment: I am not very expert in jquery,
Can You take me an example of the file js with 2-3 images?

Thanks,

Daniele

Comment: Thanks for the answer..I am not very expert in jquery, Can You take me an example of the file js with 2-3 images? Thanks, Daniele